# Grab UI input parameter to make a global object in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to setup a shiny app where I want to give user three steps to play with data. Here I have constructed an example. Data is generated in the first step with user input (length of the data). In second step user decides what parameter he wants to use to multiply the data. In the third, he gets sum of the vector for the number of rows he inputs. This example is kind of similar to my scenario. In my real scenario, 1st step is pulling data from server for parameters user decides & it takes lot of time. And I don't want to repeat this step in the latter steps. I am just trying to figure out a method to make this happen only once and the latter steps uses the `data` generated in the first step.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Reactivity & Global Variable"),

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("box1", "Observations", "100"),
        actionButton("go1", "Go"),
        br(),
        textInput("box2", "Multiplication Factor", "2"),
        actionButton("go2", "Go"),
        br(),
        textInput("box3", "Rows to Add", "50"),
        actionButton("go3", "Go"),
        br()
      ),

      mainPanel(
        h3(textOutput("obox1", container = span)),
        h3(textOutput("obox2", container = span)),
        h3(textOutput("obox3", container = span))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  a1st<-eventReactive(input$go1, {
    input$box1
  })

  output$obox1 <- renderText({
    data<-seq(1:as.numeric(a1st())
  })

  a2st<-eventReactive(input$go2, {
    input$box2
  })


  output$obox2 <- renderText({
    data<-seq(1:as.numeric(a1st()))
    data*as.numeric(a2st())
  })

  a3st<-eventReactive(input$go3, {
    input$box3
  })

  output$obox3 <- renderText({
    data<-seq(1:as.numeric(a1st()))
    data<-data*as.numeric(a2st())
    sum(data[1:as.numeric(a3st())])
  })
})
```

Comment: Not for other session, but for other steps. User inputs for step 2 and step 3 will depend on the data they see generated in step 1 (go1).

Comment: Is `data<-a1st() ` step generating data object or calling it from global environment?

Comment: Its get `a1st()` , its not regenerate `a1st()` you can check it ` a1st<-eventReactive(input$go1, {
    print("generate")
    
    seq(1:as.numeric(input$box1))
  })`   `generate` printed only if you click `go1`, you not need global enviroment if you dont want to save data between session( you can use `reactiveValues` or `reactiveEvent` which changed only if `go1`) .

Comment: okay I will check whether it works with my scenario. Could you clarify go2 & go3 steps are not creating the data object again? INstead they use the data object generated in the step 1?

Comment: In my project if i need to get some big data.. i use shinyjs to hide buttons and show waiting msg.. ( may be helpful)

Comment: `eventReactive` changed only if event in expr .. without this event it used like `reactiveValues` ( my mind.. i never used reactiveEvent before.. simple used `observeEvent+ reativeValues`)

Comment: @Batanichek, Can you provide your comment as answer? It worked, and I would like to make it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
a1st<-eventReactive(input$go1, { seq(1:as.numeric(input$box1)) }) 
output$obox1 <- renderText({ a1st() }) 

a2st<-eventReactive(input$go2, { input$box2 })

output$obox2 <- renderText({ data<-a1st() data*as.numeric(a2st()) }) 

a3st<-eventReactive(input$go3, { input$box3 }) 
output$obox3 <- renderText({ data<-a1st() data<-data*as.numeric(a2st()) sum(data[1:as.numeric(a3st())]) })
 })
```

To check that data generated only one times you can add `print`

`a1st<-eventReactive(input$go1, { print("generate") seq(1:as.numeric(input$box1)) })`

"generate" printed only if you click `go1`,

you not need use global enviroment if you dont want to save data between sessions( you can use `reactiveValues` or `reactiveEvent` which changed only if `go1`)